# What's this _n_ Ruby koans?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying out Ruby koans and found some tests using this `_n_` , never seen it before what is it and how do I use it?

Example:

```
def test_objects_have_methods
           fido = Dog.new
           assert fido.methods.size > _n_
end
```

// John

Comment: It's easier to understand what's going on if you post a link to the koan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it:

```
 # Numeric replacement value.
    def _n_(value=999999, value19=:mu)
      if RUBY_VERSION < "1.9"
        value
      else
        (value19 == :mu) ? value : value19
      end
    end
```

Comment: Ok, but what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a variable. Variable names in ruby can use underscores (even at fist and last positions). Try ctrl-clicking it in your IDE and you'll probably see its declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that `_n_` isn't one of the "fill in the blanks" parts?

Answer (score 0):

it is just another blank that needs to be filled. just replace *n* with right number of methods (for ex, 0 ) to solve this assertion error in your ruby koans.
let me know if it works